# mySQL INSERT to multiple tables using PHP statments

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling to insert mySQL data into multiple tables using PHP statements.

I have two tables:

**user**

user_ID (PK)

first_name

last_name

email

password

**profile**

profile_ID (PK)

user_ID (FK)

profile_image

profile_image_name

I update the user table like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, email, password)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[first_name]', '$_POST[last_name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[password]')";
```

The user_ID is set to auto increment in the database, so when this code is executed the inserted data is automatically assigned to a unique PK, and stored in a session. At this same point though (creating the account) I need to insert the user_ID into the profile table as the FK. That way when the user uploads their profile image, it will be assigned to they will have a record in the profile table.

For example, on the image upload page I'm using this code:

```
        $user_ID = $_SESSION['login'];


        $ins1 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE profile SET `profile_image_name`='" . $profile_image_name . "' WHERE `user_ID`='$user_ID'");
        $ins2 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE profile SET `profile_image`='" . $profile_image . "' WHERE `user_ID`='$user_ID'");
```

This code only works if the user_ID FK is already present in the profile table so how do I insert it using php statements like the one I did earlier? I tried using the first approach again but it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `insert_id` for get last PK auto increment that you insert on Mysql

http://php.net/manual/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

Insert creates a new record, update changes an existing record. With your current scheme you need to INSERT into profile. Obviously this would mean that you can't use the same code to create a profile as you use to change a profile. But there is a further option REPLACE has the same syntax as INSERT, but will overwrite an existing record.

However if each user only has a single profile, the details should be held in a single table, not two.

Comment: Storing passwords as plain text is a very bad idea, go read up on password hashing. You should also have a Google for SQL injection; your authentication is trivial to bypass and easy to destroy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO
`profile`(`user_ID`,`profile_image`,`profile_image_name`)
VALUES
('$user_ID','$profile_image','$profile_image_name')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`profile_image`='$profile_image',`profile_image_name`='$profile_image_name'
```

`user_ID` must be unique